# error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory Python 3.4

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cl

I've been trying to install pyodbc 3.0.7 by running python setup.py install but continue to have problems. Currently I've hit the "error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory" wall. I've looked online for longer than I'd like to admit trying to figure out what is going on.

I'm using a 64 bit version of Python 3.4

I've got Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0.

I've confirmed that vcvarsall.bat is in Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC.

I am running 64 bit so I added the amd64 folder and put vcvars64.bat inside Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\amd64

I confirmed cl.exe is in Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin

I've restarted my computer just to make sure that wasn't the problem.

But when I trying installing pyodbc I get the following

```
C:\Users\William\Downloads\pyodbc-3.0.7\pyodbc-3.0.7>python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing pyodbc.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to pyodbc.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to pyodbc.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'pyodbc.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching 'tests\*'
writing manifest file 'pyodbc.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
running install_lib
running build_ext
building 'pyodbc' extension
creating build
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.4
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\Users
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\Users\William
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\Users\William\Downloads
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\Users\William\Downloads\pyodbc-3.0.7
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\Users\William\Downloads\pyodbc-3.0.7\pyodbc-3.0.7
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\Users\William\Downloads\pyodbc-3.0.7\pyodbc-3.0.7\src
cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DPYODBC_VERSION=3.0.7 -IC:\Python34\include -IC:\Python34\include /TpC:\Users\William\Downloads\pyodbc-3.0.7\pyodbc-3.0.7\src\buffer.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\Users\William\Downloads\pyodbc-3.0.7\pyodbc-3.0.7\src\buffer.obj /Wall /wd4668 /wd4820 /wd4711 /wd4100 /wd4127 /wd4191
error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory
```

From there, as a last ditch effort I tried to clean and build but got the same issue.

```
C:\Users\William\Downloads\pyodbc-3.0.7\pyodbc-3.0.7>py -3 setup.py clean --all build_ext --force
running clean
removing 'build\temp.win-amd64-3.4' (and everything under it)
'build\lib.win-amd64-3.4' does not exist -- can't clean it
'build\bdist.win-amd64' does not exist -- can't clean it
'build\scripts-3.4' does not exist -- can't clean it
removing 'build'
running build_ext
building 'pyodbc' extension
creating build
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.4
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\Users
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\Users\William
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\Users\William\Downloads
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\Users\William\Downloads\pyodbc-3.0.7
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\Users\William\Downloads\pyodbc-3.0.7\pyodbc-3.0.7
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\Users\William\Downloads\pyodbc-3.0.7\pyodbc-3.0.7\src
cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DPYODBC_VERSION=3.0.7 -IC:\Python34\include -IC:\Python34\include /TpC:\Users\William\Downloads\pyodbc-3.0.7\pyodbc-3.0.7\src\buffer.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\Users\William\Downloads\pyodbc-3.0.7\pyodbc-3.0.7\src\buffer.obj /Wall /wd4668 /wd4820 /wd4711 /wd4100 /wd4127 /wd4191
error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory
```

I've always used pip so this isn't something I'm familiar with so maybe I did something wrong. Any help and I'd be eternally grateful as I think I've exhausted all resources at this point. (Or a prebuilt copy of pyodbc 3.0.7 would also work!)

Comment: I just removed the Python tags. The simple reason is that Python just tries to invoke `cl.exe` (which is the Microsoft compiler), but it shouldn't work regardless of who invokes it. So, basically, your problem boils down to the fact that you can't run `cl.exe` on the commandline.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory when installing Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43980405/cl-exe-failed-no-such-file-or-directory-when-installing-scrapy)

Answer (score 0):

You probably try to build from default `Command Prompt`. This does not work.

You must prepare a `Command Prompt`. I used the following command to get a commandline with the right settings:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /E:ON /V:ON /T:0E /K "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\SetEnv.cmd" /RELEASE /x64
```

You could create a new shortcut on the desktop, so that you do not have to type it when you want to install a new python modules.

Now You can run a new `Command Prompt` and build a `Python` packages.

Comment: Your approach is correct. However, I believe that the correct setup can be achieved by simply running a batch script that is provided with VS *from the same command prompt*. The script is exactly the `vcvarsall.bat` that's mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.4 requires Visual Studio 2010 to compile packages like pyodbc, so if you have a different version installed that's definitely the problem. Simply reinstall Visual Studio and everything should work fine!
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691
If you still have problems consider changing to 3.5 or 3.6 which will soon come out!

Hope it helped,
Stam