# cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory when installing Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to install Scrapy framework.
After installing all dependent libraries and start installing setup.py file, I get this error message: "cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory"
I'm working with python 3.6, Windows 7 64 bits.
Here is the full error message:

```
    copying src\twisted\trial\_dist\test\test_worker.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\t
wisted\trial\_dist\test
    copying src\twisted\trial\_dist\test\test_workerreporter.py -> build\lib.win
32-3.6\twisted\trial\_dist\test
    copying src\twisted\trial\_dist\test\test_workertrial.py -> build\lib.win32-
3.6\twisted\trial\_dist\test
    copying src\twisted\trial\_dist\test\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twis
ted\trial\_dist\test
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\web\test
    copying src\twisted\web\test\requesthelper.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted
\web\test
    copying src\twisted\web\test\test_agent.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\we
b\test
    copying src\twisted\web\test\test_error.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\we
b\test
    copying src\twisted\web\test\test_flatten.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\
web\test
    copying src\twisted\web\test\test_http.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\web
\test
    copying src\twisted\web\test\test_http2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\we
b\test
    copying src\twisted\web\test\test_httpauth.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted
\web\test
    copying src\twisted\web\test\test_http_headers.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twi
sted\web\test
    copying src\twisted\web\test\test_newclient.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twiste
d\web\test
    copying src\twisted\web\test\test_proxy.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\we
b\test
    copying src\twisted\web\test\test_resource.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted
\web\test
    copying src\twisted\web\test\test_script.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\w
eb\test
    copying src\twisted\web\test\test_stan.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\web
\test
    copying src\twisted\web\test\test_static.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\w
eb\test
    copying src\twisted\web\test\test_tap.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\web\
test
    copying src\twisted\web\test\test_template.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted
\web\test
    copying src\twisted\web\test\test_util.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\web
\test
    copying src\twisted\web\test\test_vhost.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\we
b\test
    copying src\twisted\web\test\test_web.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\web\
test
    copying src\twisted\web\test\test_webclient.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twiste
d\web\test
    copying src\twisted\web\test\test_web__responses.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\t
wisted\web\test
    copying src\twisted\web\test\test_wsgi.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\web
\test
    copying src\twisted\web\test\test_xmlrpc.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\w
eb\test
    copying src\twisted\web\test\_util.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\web\tes
t
    copying src\twisted\web\test\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\web\
test
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\web\_auth
    copying src\twisted\web\_auth\basic.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\web\_a
uth
    copying src\twisted\web\_auth\digest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\web\_
auth
    copying src\twisted\web\_auth\wrapper.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\web\
_auth
    copying src\twisted\web\_auth\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\web
\_auth
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\words\im
    copying src\twisted\words\im\baseaccount.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\w
ords\im
    copying src\twisted\words\im\basechat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\word
s\im
    copying src\twisted\words\im\basesupport.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\w
ords\im
    copying src\twisted\words\im\interfaces.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\wo
rds\im
    copying src\twisted\words\im\ircsupport.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\wo
rds\im
    copying src\twisted\words\im\locals.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\words\
im
    copying src\twisted\words\im\pbsupport.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\wor
ds\im
    copying src\twisted\words\im\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\word
s\im
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\words\protocols
    copying src\twisted\words\protocols\irc.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\wo
rds\protocols
    copying src\twisted\words\protocols\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twist
ed\words\protocols
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\words\test
    copying src\twisted\words\test\test_basechat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twist
ed\words\test
    copying src\twisted\words\test\test_basesupport.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\tw
isted\words\test
    copying src\twisted\words\test\test_domish.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted
\words\test
    copying src\twisted\words\test\test_irc.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\wo
rds\test
    copying src\twisted\words\test\test_ircsupport.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twi
sted\words\test
    copying src\twisted\words\test\test_irc_service.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\tw
isted\words\test
    copying src\twisted\words\test\test_jabberclient.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\t
wisted\words\test
    copying src\twisted\words\test\test_jabbercomponent.py -> build\lib.win32-3.
6\twisted\words\test
    copying src\twisted\words\test\test_jabbererror.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\tw
isted\words\test
    copying src\twisted\words\test\test_jabberjid.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twis
ted\words\test
    copying src\twisted\words\test\test_jabberjstrports.py -> build\lib.win32-3.
6\twisted\words\test
    copying src\twisted\words\test\test_jabbersasl.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twi
sted\words\test
    copying src\twisted\words\test\test_jabbersaslmechanisms.py -> build\lib.win
32-3.6\twisted\words\test
    copying src\twisted\words\test\test_jabberxmlstream.py -> build\lib.win32-3.
6\twisted\words\test
    copying src\twisted\words\test\test_jabberxmppstringprep.py -> build\lib.win
32-3.6\twisted\words\test
    copying src\twisted\words\test\test_service.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twiste
d\words\test
    copying src\twisted\words\test\test_xishutil.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twist
ed\words\test
    copying src\twisted\words\test\test_xmlstream.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twis
ted\words\test
    copying src\twisted\words\test\test_xmpproutertap.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\
twisted\words\test
    copying src\twisted\words\test\test_xpath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\
words\test
    copying src\twisted\words\test\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\wo
rds\test
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\words\xish
    copying src\twisted\words\xish\domish.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\word
s\xish
    copying src\twisted\words\xish\utility.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\wor
ds\xish
    copying src\twisted\words\xish\xmlstream.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\w
ords\xish
    copying src\twisted\words\xish\xpath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\words
\xish
    copying src\twisted\words\xish\xpathparser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted
\words\xish
    copying src\twisted\words\xish\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\wo
rds\xish
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\words\protocols\jabber
    copying src\twisted\words\protocols\jabber\client.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\
twisted\words\protocols\jabber
    copying src\twisted\words\protocols\jabber\component.py -> build\lib.win32-3
.6\twisted\words\protocols\jabber
    copying src\twisted\words\protocols\jabber\error.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\t
wisted\words\protocols\jabber
    copying src\twisted\words\protocols\jabber\ijabber.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6
\twisted\words\protocols\jabber
    copying src\twisted\words\protocols\jabber\jid.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twi
sted\words\protocols\jabber
    copying src\twisted\words\protocols\jabber\jstrports.py -> build\lib.win32-3
.6\twisted\words\protocols\jabber
    copying src\twisted\words\protocols\jabber\sasl.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\tw
isted\words\protocols\jabber
    copying src\twisted\words\protocols\jabber\sasl_mechanisms.py -> build\lib.w
in32-3.6\twisted\words\protocols\jabber
    copying src\twisted\words\protocols\jabber\xmlstream.py -> build\lib.win32-3
.6\twisted\words\protocols\jabber
    copying src\twisted\words\protocols\jabber\xmpp_stringprep.py -> build\lib.w
in32-3.6\twisted\words\protocols\jabber
    copying src\twisted\words\protocols\jabber\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.
6\twisted\words\protocols\jabber
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\_threads\test
    copying src\twisted\_threads\test\test_convenience.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6
\twisted\_threads\test
    copying src\twisted\_threads\test\test_memory.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twis
ted\_threads\test
    copying src\twisted\_threads\test\test_team.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twiste
d\_threads\test
    copying src\twisted\_threads\test\test_threadworker.py -> build\lib.win32-3.
6\twisted\_threads\test
    copying src\twisted\_threads\test\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted
\_threads\test
    running egg_info
    writing src\Twisted.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to src\Twisted.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing entry points to src\Twisted.egg-info\entry_points.txt
    writing requirements to src\Twisted.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to src\Twisted.egg-info\top_level.txt
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'src\Twisted.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.misc' found under director
y 'src\twisted'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.bugfix' found under direct
ory 'src\twisted'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.doc' found under directory
 'src\twisted'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.feature' found under direc
tory 'src\twisted'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.removal' found under direc
tory 'src\twisted'
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'NEWS' found under directory
'src\twisted'
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'README' found under director
y 'src\twisted'
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'topfiles' found under direct
ory 'src\twisted'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'src\twisted\topfiles\C
REDITS'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'src\twisted\topfiles\C
hangeLog.Old'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'appveyor.yml'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bin'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'admin'
    no previously-included directories found matching '.travis'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'docs\historic\2003'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'do
cs\historic\2003'
    writing manifest file 'src\Twisted.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    copying src\twisted\python\_sendmsg.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\python
    copying src\twisted\python\twisted-completion.zsh -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twi
sted\python
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\python\_pydoctortemplates
    copying src\twisted\python\_pydoctortemplates\common.html -> build\lib.win32
-3.6\twisted\python\_pydoctortemplates
    copying src\twisted\python\_pydoctortemplates\index.html -> build\lib.win32-
3.6\twisted\python\_pydoctortemplates
    copying src\twisted\python\_pydoctortemplates\summary.html -> build\lib.win3
2-3.6\twisted\python\_pydoctortemplates
    copying src\twisted\runner\portmap.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\runner
    copying src\twisted\test\raiser.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\test
    copying src\twisted\test\raiser.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\test
    copying src\twisted\test\server.pem -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\test
    copying src\twisted\internet\iocpreactor\build.bat -> build\lib.win32-3.6\tw
isted\internet\iocpreactor
    copying src\twisted\internet\iocpreactor\notes.txt -> build\lib.win32-3.6\tw
isted\internet\iocpreactor
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\internet\iocpreactor\iocpsupport
    copying src\twisted\internet\iocpreactor\iocpsupport\acceptex.pxi -> build\l
ib.win32-3.6\twisted\internet\iocpreactor\iocpsupport
    copying src\twisted\internet\iocpreactor\iocpsupport\connectex.pxi -> build\
lib.win32-3.6\twisted\internet\iocpreactor\iocpsupport
    copying src\twisted\internet\iocpreactor\iocpsupport\iocpsupport.c -> build\
lib.win32-3.6\twisted\internet\iocpreactor\iocpsupport
    copying src\twisted\internet\iocpreactor\iocpsupport\iocpsupport.pyx -> buil
d\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\internet\iocpreactor\iocpsupport
    copying src\twisted\internet\iocpreactor\iocpsupport\winsock_pointers.c -> b
uild\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\internet\iocpreactor\iocpsupport
    copying src\twisted\internet\iocpreactor\iocpsupport\winsock_pointers.h -> b
uild\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\internet\iocpreactor\iocpsupport
    copying src\twisted\internet\iocpreactor\iocpsupport\wsarecv.pxi -> build\li
b.win32-3.6\twisted\internet\iocpreactor\iocpsupport
    copying src\twisted\internet\iocpreactor\iocpsupport\wsasend.pxi -> build\li
b.win32-3.6\twisted\internet\iocpreactor\iocpsupport
    copying src\twisted\internet\test\_awaittests.py.3only -> build\lib.win32-3.
6\twisted\internet\test
    copying src\twisted\internet\test\_yieldfromtests.py.3only -> build\lib.win3
2-3.6\twisted\internet\test
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs
    copying src\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs\chain.pem -> build\lib.win32-3.6\
twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs
    copying src\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs\not-a-certificate -> build\lib.wi
n32-3.6\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs
    copying src\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs\thing1.pem -> build\lib.win32-3.6
\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs
    copying src\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs\thing2-duplicate.pem -> build\lib
.win32-3.6\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs
    copying src\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs\thing2.pem -> build\lib.win32-3.6
\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\mail\test
    copying src\twisted\mail\test\rfc822.message -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\
mail\test
    copying src\twisted\words\im\instancemessenger.glade -> build\lib.win32-3.6\
twisted\words\im
    copying src\twisted\words\xish\xpathparser.g -> build\lib.win32-3.6\twisted\
words\xish
    running build_ext
    building 'twisted.test.raiser' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.6
    creating build\temp.win32-3.6\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\src
    creating build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\src\twisted
    creating build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\src\twisted\test
    cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DWIN32=1 -Ic:\users\yassine\appd
ata\local\programs\python\python36-32\include -Ic:\users\yassine\appdata\local\p
rograms\python\python36-32\include /Tcsrc/twisted/test/raiser.c /Fobuild\temp.wi
n32-3.6\Release\src/twisted/test/raiser.obj
    error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory
```

Maybe the question is not well explained, But I'm here to respond to any question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've met the same problem after I installed the latest version of Visual Studio. Here's the solution that worked out in the end:

1. Visit: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
2. Download the correct version of Twisted and Lxml accordingly (your python version system version).
3. pip install twisted and lxml before pip install scrapy

Answer (score 2):

`cl.exe` is the *Microsoft C/C++ compiler* (included in MS Visual C++ / MS Visual Studio.)

Either you don't have it, or it is not in your `PATH` environment variable.

You may search for it in your computer (e.g. with help of the very efficient free program [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/)) and then add it to your `PATH` variable (you may use the free program [Rapid Environment Editor](https://www.rapidee.com/en/download)).

Then prepare your environment by launching `vcvarsall.bat` batch file (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7865708/7023590)) and you will be ready to  reinstalling `Scrapy`.

Answer (score 0):

As it is said in the [scrapy documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#platform-specific-installation-notes), it is recommended to install scrapy on Windows with [Anaconda](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install-windows). It's a `virtualenv`, so it will make a clean install of scrapy on your system, and all the dependencies will be automatically installed.

Once Anaconda is installed you enter this cmd in your console: `conda install -c conda-forge scrapy` and you should be fine.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html)

you need to install:

- Twisted 14.0
- lxml 3.4
- pyOpenSSL 0.14

so run :

```
pip3 install Twisted==14.0 lxml pyOpenSSL Scrapy
```